# Link DE in Contact Builder (Salesforce Marketing Cloud)

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, contactbuilder

I am building a new journey where the entry source will be a contact object.  I want to write back all journey activities for each record to a separate DE in Marketing Cloud.

I know I will need to link this DE in contact builder, to create and "Update Contact" activity in the Journey.  How and where do I create this link to the DE?  I do not want to break my present contact model build by linking my DE incorrectly.

Any help you can provide would be great!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out that I need to turn Sendable DE to Yes, I did not need to link the DE to the contact model.  Thanks for the help, SFMC Trailblazer Community.